# How can I determine if a cell is vertically merged in PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

I've looked all the properties & methods in the PowerPoint interfaces Table, Row, & Cell. While Cell has a way to split & merge cells, none have a way to determine if a cell is presently merged. Is there a way to do this?

We use the COM (not VSTO) API if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, this is an ongoing problem with tables and VBA, there isn't any method in the object model to accurately determine which cells have been merged or split. This thread alludes to the problem and a workaround (but it's clunky): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365559/vba-powerpoint-merge-cells-in-loop

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you - klunky but it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/), it will be easy to check if a table cell is merged. You would know all necessary information about merged cells. The following code example shows how you can do this.

```cs
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < table.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        ICell cell = table.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        if (cell.IsMergedCell)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The merged cell [{rowIndex},{columnIndex}] was found.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Row span: {cell.RowSpan}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Column span: {cell.ColSpan}");
            Console.WriteLine($"The first row index: {cell.FirstRowIndex}");
            Console.WriteLine($"The first column index: {cell.FirstColumnIndex}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, we can compare the height of the cell and the row. If they are different, it means the cell is merged vertically. The following function determines whether the given cell is merged vertically or horizontally.

```
'simply check if the cell is merged
Function IsMerged(oTbl As Table, rr As Integer, cc As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim c As Cell

    'the current cell
    Set c = oTbl.Cell(rr, cc)

    'Check the width and height
    'horizonatally merged
    If c.Shape.Width <> oTbl.Columns(cc).Width Then IsMerged = True
    'vertically merged
    If c.Shape.Height <> oTbl.Rows(rr).Height Then IsMerged = True

End Function
```

We can also identify if the cell is the Top-Left(first) cell of the merged area by following method:

```
Function isTopLeftCell(oTbl As Table, rr As Integer, cc As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With oTbl.Cell(rr, cc).Shape
        'horizontally merged
        If .Width <> oTbl.Columns(cc).Width Then
            'count the left cells merged from the currnet cell
            For i = 1 To cc - 1
                If oTbl.Cell(rr, cc - i).Shape.Left <> .Left Then Exit For
            Next i
            'count the rows above
            If i = 1 Then
                For i = 1 To rr - 1
                    If oTbl.Cell(rr - i, cc).Shape.Top <> .Top Then Exit For
                Next i
                If i = 1 Then isTopLeftCell = True: Exit Function
            End If
        'vertically merged
        ElseIf .Height <> oTbl.Rows(rr).Height Then
            For i = 1 To rr - 1
                If oTbl.Cell(rr - i, cc).Shape.Top <> .Top Then Exit For
            Next i
            If i = 1 Then isTopLeftCell = True: Exit Function
        Else
            'isTopLeftCell = False
        End If
    End With
    
End Function
```

The following returns the width(ww) and height(hh) of the merged area

```
    'Returns the width and height of the merged area
Function getMergedArea(oTbl As Table, rr As Integer, cc As Integer, ByRef ww As Integer, ByRef hh As Integer)
    Dim c As Cell
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    Set c = oTbl.Cell(rr, cc)
    'ww = 1: hh = 1
    
    ww = c.Shape.Width / oTbl.Columns(cc).Width
    hh = c.Shape.Height / oTbl.Rows(rr).Height

End Function
```

If you want get the index no. of the cell in the merged area:
(which is the result of my hard working!)

```
    'Returns the index no. of the cell : top to bottom, left to right
Function getMergedIndex(oTbl As Table, rr As Integer, cc As Integer) As Integer

    Dim c As Cell
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, mc As Integer
    
    Set c = oTbl.Cell(rr, cc)
    
    'horizontally merged
    If c.Shape.Width <> oTbl.Columns(cc).Width Then

        'get the horizontal index
        For i = 1 To cc - 1
            If oTbl.Cell(rr, cc - i).Shape.Left <> c.Shape.Left Then Exit For
        Next i
        
        'get the merged row count above
        For j = 1 To rr - 1
            If oTbl.Cell(rr - j, cc).Shape.Top <> c.Shape.Top Then Exit For
        Next j
        'if merged both horizontally and vertically
        If j > 1 Then
            'get the column count of the merged cells above
            mc = oTbl.Cell(rr - 1, cc).Shape.Width / oTbl.Columns(cc).Width
            'For mc = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count - cc
            '    If oTbl.Cell(rr - 1, cc + mc).Shape.Left <> c.Shape.Left Then Exit For
            'Next mc
            'mc = i + mc - 1
            'add up to the merged cells above
            getMergedIndex = (j - 1) * mc + i
        Else
            getMergedIndex = i
        End If
        
    'vertically merged
    ElseIf c.Shape.Height <> oTbl.Rows(rr).Height Then

        For i = 1 To rr - 1
            If oTbl.Cell(rr - i, cc).Shape.Top <> c.Shape.Top Then Exit For
        Next i
        getMergedIndex = i
    Else
        'not merged
    End If
    
End Function

''For example:
''[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
''[  ][01][02][03][04][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
''[  ][05][06][07][08][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
''[  ][  ][01][02][03][04][01][02][  ][  ]
''[  ][  ][05][06][07][08][03][04][  ][  ]
''[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][05][06][  ][  ]
''[01][02][03][04][01][  ][07][08][01][02]
''[05][06][07][08][02][  ][  ][  ][03][04]
''[01][02][03][04][  ][  ][  ][  ][05][06]
''[05][06][07][08][  ][  ][  ][  ][07][08]
```

finally, check if two given cells are contained within a merged area

```
Function isMerged2(oTbl As Table, r1%, c1%, r2%, c2%) As Boolean
    If oTbl.Cell(r1, c1).Shape.Left = oTbl.Cell(r2, c2).Shape.Left And _
        oTbl.Cell(r1, c1).Shape.Top = oTbl.Cell(r2, c2).Shape.Top And _
        oTbl.Cell(r1, c1).Shape.Width = oTbl.Cell(r2, c2).Shape.Width And _
        oTbl.Cell(r1, c1).Shape.Height = oTbl.Cell(r2, c2).Shape.Height Then _
            isMerged2 = True
End Function
```